# Loop and Build HTML DOM using array values

Tags: php

I am having a difficult time understanding how to call specific how the `foreach` command will allow me to call to display the requirements.

```
<?php

$html = array(
    array(
        'tag_name' => 'h1',
        'content' => 'My page title'
    ),
    array(
        'tag_name' => 'p',
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'big shiny'
        ),
        'content' => 'Pizza is one of the main food groups. 5 out of 4 dentists recommend pizza over any other form of nutrition. Thou shalt eat thine pizza.'
    ),
    array(
        'tag_name' => 'label',
        'attributes' => array(
            'for' => 'like_pizza'
        ),
        'content' => 'Do you like pizza?'
    ),
    array(
        'tag_name' => 'input',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'id' => 'like_pizza',
            'name' => 'like_pizza',
            'checked' => 'checked'
        )
    )
);

?>
```

How do I use a `foreach` loop to output the following HTML.

```
<h1>My Page Title</h1>
<p class="big shiny">Pizza is one of the main food groups. 5 out of 4 dentists recommend pizza over any other form of nutrition. Thou shalt eat thine pizza.</p>
<label for="like_pizza">Do you like pizza?</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="like_pizza" name="like_pizza" checked="checked">
```

Comment: You're going to need to create a recursive function; I'm currently working on a base model to help you, but give me a second.

Comment: Nevermind, others already added their solution.

Comment: Please consider to mark one of the multiple correct answers given as the answer^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all review this http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php please ( just for education ).

The approach ( as with all tree like structures, thus, markup langauges like HTML, XML and whatever data representation behind ) is to use recursion.

Consequently you only have to consider the first level for evaluation of the tag itself and then catch exceptional cases.

```
<?php
$html = array(
    array(
        'tag_name'=>'h1',
        'content'=>'My page title'
    ),
    array(
        'tag_name'=>'p',
        'attributes'=>array(
            'class'=>'big shiny'
        ),
        'content'=>'Pizza is one of the main food groups. 5 out of 4 dentists recommend pizza over any other form of nutrition. Thou shalt eat thine pizza.'
    ),
    array(
        'tag_name'=>'label',
        'attributes'=>array(
            'for'=>'like_pizza'
        ),
        'content'=>'Do you like pizza?'
    ),
    array(
        'tag_name'=>'input',
        'attributes'=>array(
            'type'=>'checkbox',
            'id'=>'like_pizza',
            'name'=>'like_pizza',
            'checked'=>'checked'
        )
    )
);
?>
```

Having corrected your indentation look at your format:
Of course the root is an array containing only arrays. Each of these arrays contains key<->value pairs that make up information of one tag.

Consequently you have to write a function that can handle the information and transform it into a tag string representation.

```
function formatTag($tag, $attributes, $content)
{
    $str = "<".$tag;
    foreach($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue)
    {
        $val = $attrValue;
        if(is_array($attrValue)) // Consider multiple class assignments!
          foreach($attrValue as $value)
             $val .= $value.' ';

        $str .= ' '.$attrName.'="'.$val.'"';
    }
    $str .= ">".$content."</".$tag.">";

    return $str;
}

function handleTagArray($arr) {
    if(!array_key_exists("tag_name"))
        throw new Exception("Invalid format!");

    $tag = $arr["tag_name"];
    $attributes = array_key_exists("attributes") ? $arr["attributes"] : "";
    $content = array_key_exists("content") ? $arr["content"] : "";
    if(is_array($content))
    {
        foreach($content as $child) // One tag could have multiple children!
        {
            if(is_array($child)) // Distinguish mixed children types tag or text here!
                $content .= handleTagArray($child);
            else 
                $content .= $child;
    }

    return formatTag($tag, $attributes, $content);
}
```

This solution takes into account that one tag can have multiple children.

```
array ( 'tag_name'=> 'body',
        'content' => array (
                       array ( 'tag_name' => 'h1',
                               'content' => 'My page title' 
                       ),
                       array ( 'tag_name' => 'p',
                               'attributes' // ...
                     )
       );
```

This solution also takes tags like this into account `<div id="test" class="testdiv noborder fullwidth">Test</div>`, i.e. the possibility to have multiple classes for a tag. You have to write this accordingly in your array structure:

```
//...
array( 'tag_name' => 'div',
       'attributes' => array('id'=>'test', 'class'=>array('testdiv', 'noborder', 'fullwidth')), 
       'content' => 'Test' );
```

Consider in addition that by default XML and HTML require you to have one root node, i.e. the first array should contain tag info as well and the children should be wrapped in its content array.

---

EDIT: Adjusted my code according to @faino s remarks on array_key_exists. Learnt something new today. :D Thanks faino!

---

EDIT: Added distinction between children types tag <-> text, see code!

Comment: nice one. but what do you do, when you have a content and also childs?

Comment: The children are by definition the content. So what you need to do is to loop over the children, check if its an array or text and handle accordingly. I'm gonna update my code to make it clear.

Comment: i'm not sure, but with this `if(is_array($content))` you'll never reach the part, where the child is text ;)

Comment: @RaphaelMüller you will. If the content is a string is_array is false and the direct assignment of the text to the content will be executed. Strings to not evaluate to arrays in is_array!

( http://www.php.net//manual/de/function.is-array.php )

Comment: Ah you mean the first of it. Of couse, with the poster's original format you won't! Consequently he has to correct his format to make it work, which is what I mentioned and display by an example in my answer. :D

Comment: exactly ;) the array has to have the correct format

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do the trick, it's kinda rough but it's a good start for you to learn from. Look into the [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) and [foreach](http://www.php.net//manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) documentation for a better understanding and more examples.

```
<?php
    $html = array(
        array(
            'tag_name'=>'h1',
            'content'=>'My page title'
        ),
        array(
            'tag_name'=>'p',
            'attributes'=>array(
                'class'=>'big shiny'
            ),
            'content'=>'Pizza is one of the main food groups. 5 out of 4 dentists recommend pizza over any other form of nutrition. Thou shalt eat thine pizza.'
        ),
        array(
            'tag_name'=>'label',
            'attributes'=>array(
                'for'=>'like_pizza'
            ),
            'content'=>'Do you like pizza?'
        ),
        array(
            'tag_name'=>'input',
            'attributes'=>array(
                'type'=>'checkbox',
                'id'=>'like_pizza',
                'name'=>'like_pizza',
                'checked'=>'checked'
            )
        )
    );
    // ECHO this function where needed
    function format_array($arr) {
        $output = "";
        foreach($arr as $inner) {
            $output .= "<" . $inner["tag_name"];
            if(array_key_exists("attributes", $inner)) {
                foreach($inner["attributes"] as $name => $val) {
                    $output .= " " . $name . "=\"" . $val . "\"";
                }
            }
            $output .= ">";
            if(array_key_exists("content", $inner)) {
                $output .= $inner["content"] . "</" . $inner["tag_name"] . ">";
            }
        }
        return($output);
    }
    // Display the HTML
    echo(format_array($html));
?>
```

You would just call that function with the array in question and echo it within your HTML.

Comment: you missed the recursive ones ;)

Comment: I have a little live demo up, and you can see it's outputting the HTML just fine as requested: http://allyumassage.com/test.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use a recursive function.

```
function display($data){
    foreach($data as $inner)
    {
        $ret = "<".$inner['tag'];
        if(is_array($inner['attributes'])                //check if there are attributes
        foreach($inner['attributes'] as $key => $value){
           $ret .= ' '.$key.'="'.$value.'"';
        }
        $ret .= ">".$inner['content'];
        if(is_array($inner['content'])) $ret .= display($inner['content']);     //call the function recursive for the nested ones
        $ret .= "</".$inner['tag'].">";
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

and use like this:

```
    echo display($html);
```

Comment: Thank you I am doing this as an assignment and was asked to use a foreach loop to accomplish the desired result  using function in next question.  I am having difficulty understanding how using the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `DOMDocument` class and use its useful methods. Consider this example:

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YJlJsM)

```
$html = array( array( 'tag_name'=>'h1', 'content'=>'My page title' ), array( 'tag_name'=>'p', 'attributes'=>array( 'class'=>'big shiny' ), 'content'=>'Pizza is one of the main food groups. 5 out of 4 dentists recommend pizza over any other form of nutrition. Thou shalt eat thine pizza.' ), array( 'tag_name'=>'label', 'attributes'=>array( 'for'=>'like_pizza' ), 'content'=>'Do you like pizza?' ), array( 'tag_name'=>'input', 'attributes'=>array( 'type'=>'checkbox', 'id'=>'like_pizza', 'name'=>'like_pizza', 'checked'=>'checked' ) ));
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<html></html>');
foreach($html as $tags) {
    $element = null;

    // tag
    if(isset($tags['tag_name'])) {
        $content = isset($tags['content']) ? $tags['content'] : '';
        $element = $dom->createElement($tags['tag_name'], $content);

    }

    // attributes
    if(isset($tags['attributes'])) {
        foreach($tags['attributes'] as $attribute_value => $value) {
            $attribute = $dom->createAttribute($attribute_value);
            $attribute->value = $value;
            $element->appendChild($attribute);
        }
    }

    $dom->appendChild($element);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```